# Change QR Scanner orientation with ZXING in Android Studio

Tags: android, camera, orientation, qr-code, zxing

I hope you can help me with this. Im using the Zxing Embedded Library in order to use the QR scanner, the problem is that is on Landscape mode and I would like to change it to Portrait.

I have this on the dependencies of my Graddle

```
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:2.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-integration:2.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.1'
```

and I have this in my java class to activate the scanner with a button...

```
public void scanQR(View view){
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setResultDisplayDuration(0);//Text..
    integrator.setPrompt(" Scan a QR Code");
    integrator.setScanningRectangle(450, 450);//size
    integrator.setCameraId(0);  // Use a specific camera of the device
    integrator.initiateScan();

}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I am using

> compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.1.0@aar'

It is different version, so I don't know if this will work for you, 
but this is working for me.

> More about my setup, I only compile
>
> 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.1.0@aar'
>
> 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.1'
>
> and I did not compile
>
> 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-integration:2.0.1@aar'

First I created an activity extend from the CaptureActivity

or click this link to view the class https://gist.github.com/TheGratefulDev/21a557c9a96333ec037c

```
public class CaptureActivityPortrait extends CaptureActivity {
//Nothing in side.
}
```

Second, add this

> integrator.setCaptureActivity(CaptureActivityPortait.class);

into your integrator code.

This is how mine looks like:

```
CustomIntegrator integrator = new CustomIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(CustomIntegrator.PDF_417);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan a barcode");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);  // Use a specific camera of the device
            integrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
            integrator.setCaptureActivity(CaptureActivityPortrait.class);
            integrator.initiateScan();
```

Finally, at the AndroidMaifest add

> ```
>    <activity
>         android:name=".custom.CaptureActivityPortrait"
>         android:screenOrientation="portrait" <---this is the most important line
>         android:stateNotNeeded="true"
>         android:theme="@style/zxing_CaptureTheme"
>         android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
>     </activity>
> ```

Comment: how you are extending captureactivity? i am getting error as can't inherit from final CaptureActivity

Comment: @Shadow I just checked my answer, I forgot zxing:core3.2.0
check the build.glade 
make sure you have this two libraries added {
'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.1.0@aar'  and 
'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0' }

Comment: @Shadow this is that class that extend from CaptureActivity 

https://gist.github.com/KaLingCode/21a557c9a96333ec037c

Comment: this is also worked for version 3.2.0 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar' @NOT_A_PROGRAMMER

Comment: I had android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" which meant my activity would switch orientation to landscape (which wasn't desirable for QR code reading). Setting it to portrait fixed it.

Comment: I tested and work in ``com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0``. Just following step by step

Comment: Instead of this android:screenOrientation="portrait" use  android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"  tools:replace="screenOrientation" setting this configuration saved my day . :)

Answer (score 56):

Instead of extending a class, just add this to the manifest:

```
  <activity
            android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:replace="android:screenOrientation"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"/>
```

Works like a charm

Comment: Thanks! Hope it helped!

Comment: You deserve the award

Comment: what if i have it on a fragment

Comment: how to turn on flash in same library?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the easiest way. We should create another CaptureActivity.java class and write this code inside `onclick` listener:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
integrator.setPrompt("Scan a barcode");
integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(integrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
integrator.setCameraId(0);  
integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);

// Replace with your own java class location here
integrator.setCaptureActivity(com.share.ants.hotelmenu.CaptureActivity.class);
integrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(YourActivity.this);
integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
integrator.setPrompt(getResources().getString(R.string.scan_a_barcode));
integrator.setCameraId(0);
// Use a specific camera of the device
integrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
integrator.initiateScan();
```