# Change screen orientation automatically while scanning (using ZXING library)

Tags: android, orientation, zxing, barcode-scanner

I've `MainActivity.kt` where I show different fragments for different needs. At some point, I press button 'X' that calls `startScanner()` function:

```
private fun startScanner() {
    IntentIntegrator(this)
            .setOrientationLocked(false)
            .setPrompt("SCANNING?")
            .initiateScan()
}
```

`Manifest.xml:`

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActiity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:screenOrientation"
    android:stateNotNeeded="true"
    android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

`Gradle.file:`

```
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
```

It does open scanner and everything, but in **landscape mode**.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Refer to this https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/385

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35465968/5518744

Answer (score 8):

There is a shortcut to do this. Just add this to the manifest:

```
<activity
       android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       tools:replace="android:screenOrientation"
       android:stateNotNeeded="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35465968/7666442

I found way to change Orientation of `zxing` scanner activity automatically when device Orientation change

Try this way

> **CaptureActivityPortrait**

```
public class CaptureActivityPortrait extends CaptureActivity {
//Nothing in side.
}
```

> `CaptureActivityPortrait` in manifest file

```
    <activity
        android:name=".CaptureActivityPortrait"
        android:stateNotNeeded="false"
        android:theme="@style/zxing_CaptureTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
```

> use this way in your activity

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    IntentIntegrator qrScan;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(this).setCaptureActivity(CaptureActivityPortrait.class);

        qrScan.setOrientationLocked(false);
        qrScan.initiateScan();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the orientation programmatically (in your activity):

[ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

[ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```