# ZXing 3.6.0 in portrait mode?

Tags: android, zxing

I use XZing 3.6.0 to scan QR codes within my Android app.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    Button btnScan;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
                scanIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            tv.setText(scanContent);
        }
        else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
```

It works... except the camera is shown in landscape mode. How to change that to portrait mode?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51375179/7666442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your Manifest File :

```
<activity
   android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   tools:replace="android:screenOrientation"
   android:stateNotNeeded="true"/>
```

Comment: Surprisingly it works. Interesting how this solution involves modifying non-Java code :)

Comment: while importing the lib you can extend and modify as you would also you can modify it proprieties inside your manifest file by calling it with package name.

Answer (score 0):

try this in XML file :

```
   <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView
            android:id="@+id/barcode_scanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:zxing_viewfinder_mask="#ffffff"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            >

        </com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView>
```

and here is the fragment code :

```
public  class ScanFragment extends Fragment {
private String toast;
private LinearLayout qrCameraLayout;
IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator;
private CompoundBarcodeView barcodeView;
private TextView tv_qr_print;


public ScanFragment() {
}


public static ScanFragment newInstance(int page, String title, ViewPager viewPager) {
    ScanFragment fragmentFirst = new ScanFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    args.putString("someTitle", title);
    fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentFirst;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    displayToast();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    intentIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_scanner, container, false);
    qrCameraLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_qrcamera);

    barcodeView = (CompoundBarcodeView) view.findViewById(R.id.barcode_scanner);
    tv_qr_print = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_qr_print);

    barcodeView.decodeContinuous(callback);
    /* View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false);*/
    CustomButton scan = (CustomButton) view.findViewById(R.id.scan_from_fragment);
    scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           /* scanFromFragment();*/
        }
    });
    return view;
}

private BarcodeCallback callback = new BarcodeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {
        if (result.getText() != null) {
            barcodeView.setStatusText(result.getText());
            tv_qr_print.setText(result.getText());
            displayToast();

        }

        //Do something with code result
    }

    @Override
    public void possibleResultPoints(List<ResultPoint> resultPoints) {
    }
};


public void scanFromFragment() {
    intentIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(true);

    intentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this).initiateScan();



}

private void displayToast() {
    if(getActivity() != null && toast != null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        toast = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            toast = "Cancelled from fragment";
        } else {
            toast = "Scanned from fragment: " + result.getContents();
        }

        // At this point we may or may not have a reference to the activity
        displayToast();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    barcodeView.resume();
    barcodeView.getViewFinder().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    barcodeView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}
}
```